# Using Dart, create byte-addressable array (or List), that can take dynamic data types?

Tags: dart

I've built a fairly basic VM and assembler using C++, and I want to do the same thing using Dart.

Is there a way to create a byte-addressable List, such that I can put integers or single characters into it and extract them from it?

I've implemented this in C++ using 
`char myArray[100];` I can put char or int types into this array by using type casting, `*(char*)(myArray) = 'a';` and `*(int*)(myArray + 1) = 5;`. 
Where a char is 1 Byte, and an integer is 4 Bytes.

I can read a value at a given index in `myArray` as an int or a char by simply using type casting again. `char myChar = *(char*)(myArray + 0);` and `int myInt = *(int*)(myArray + 1);` Resulting in `myChar == 'a'` and `myInt == 5`.

I've looked at the Dart core, convert, and URI libraries since they all have Byte-related methods or properties, but they don't quite seem to do what I'm wanting to do.

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality in Dart?

Answer (score 3):

Dart has a structured integer arrays under [`dart:typed_data`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html) - does that help?

Comment: I've been messing around with the typed_data library, I'll post again when I have a more definite success/failure status. :D